# Android samsung ace 2 gps takes a long time to aquire a lock

Tags: android, gps

i've written an app that relies heavily on GPS. It works fine on htc and other manufacturers apart from Samsung. Does Samsung or more particularly the ace 2 have a known problem with GPS lock. It works fine on my htc one X and takes around 5 secs to get a lock whereas on the Samsung it can sometimes take a minute or so if it gets a lock at all, which when the app is rolled out this time span is unacceptable. My company is to recommend 500 phones to the companies which the app is to be rolled out to, so it's very important that we distinguish whether it's a software or a hardware problem.

Would my app get a gps lock quicker if i turn AGPS on? Have any of you any experiences with this?

Does anyone know of a problem with Samsung?

Thanks in advance Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few Samsungs and they all lock to GPS pretty fast. Most probably it's the problem with your particular device, not with the maker and not with the device model.

Please, try to find (beg, borrow, steal =) another `Ace` and try your software on that device.

Comment: ok thanks, i've already suggested that to my boss. I've asked him to get a list of user's phones that it will be rolled out to eventually. We'll have to do some rigourous testing on those. Thanks:)